# Decorator or dispather for RESTful URL routing in CherryPy

Tags: rest, url-routing, decorator, cherrypy

I want to route requests in a way similar to how Python web.py or Python bottle does it.

With these frameworks you can simply add tags into the URL which can be used to pass parameters, eg:

```
@route('/api/part1/<tag1name>/part2/<tag2name>')
def handlerfunction(self, tag1name, tag2name):
```

CherryPy does have the popargs decorator, eg

```
@cherrypy.popargs('name')
```

However when there is more than one value encoded in the URI it becomes quite inconvenient to get them assigned to the parameters the right way.

In addition I want to be able to route based on the HTTP request method, as per the CherryPy MethodDispatcher.

Comment: I think it's better to do routing in CherryPy way, and these decorators are scattering routing across handlers, whereas it's better to manage them in one place (Routes dispatcher) or no place at all (default object tree traversal dispatcher). But if you're really looking for the ad-hoc way, the thing called [cherryontop](https://github.com/csira/cherryontop) was recently on CherryPy twitter. It may be not directly useful, but you may find ideas for implementing such decorator.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use a URL Route-mapping module such as "[Routes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Routes/2.1)".  "Routes" is developed firstly for Pylons but does have support for CherryPy.

From the [Documentation](https://routes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

> Routes is a Python re-implementation of the Rails routes system for mapping URLs to application actions, and conversely to generate URLs. Routes makes it easy to create pretty and concise URLs that are RESTful with little effort.

> Routes allows conditional matching based on domain, cookies, HTTP method, or a custom function. Sub-domain support is built in. Routes comes with an extensive unit test suite.

After working through the documentation and getting it to work with CherryPy I will update this answer with some CherryPy specific implementation examples.